# Toggling a class disables my link

Tags: jquery, toggle, href

I have this jquery:

```
$(".button").toggle(function() {
$(this).find(".button").addClass('disable');    
},
function(){
$(this).find(".button").removeClass('disable');
});
```

My html for .button link is:

```
<a class="button" href="/users/sign_up">
```

My css disable class:

```
.disable {
          background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F0F0 !important ;           
          border-color: #D1CDCD;
          color: #D1CDCD !important;    
          cursor:default;   
          text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(34, 25,25,0.01)!important;                           
          cursor:pointer; box-shadow: none !important;
          }
```

Why I can not go to /users/sign_up when I click the button? The .disable class is added and working fine but the link isn't taken.

Comment: Umm what would be the point of changing css of the link if you just want to go to another page?

Comment: pls show a bit more of your HTML code

Comment: why affect the css to link action? :S I dont understand, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

> The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links
>   will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has
>   been called on the element.

It would be easy to open the page manually at the end of your toggle function:

```
window.location = $(".button").attr('href');
```

Here's an [example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ESML7/).  To get it working, I had to replace `$(this).find(".button")` with `$(".button)`.